# robotframework - how to get data from changing index

Tags: json, robotframework

I have this JSON object with this layout:

```
{
    "events": [{
            "type": "page",
            "sessionId": "d9e3643a-5126-4ee4-bcc8-5fa1b4fdf52b",
            "changes": {
                "changes": [{
                            "model": {
                            "styles": ["bold"],
                            "name": "TextItem",                         
                            },
                            "type": "update",
                            "key": "1"
                            }, {
                            "model": {
                            "styles": [],
                            "name": "TextItem",
                            "plainText": "Skoda Octavia",
                            },
                            "type": "textitem",
                            "properties": {}
                            ,
                            "type": "update",
                            "key": "2"
                            }, {
                            "model": {
                            "questionText": "Bouwjaar",
                            "validations": [{
                                    "message": "Dit veld is verplicht",                     
                                }, {
                                    "message": "Voer een geldig bouwjaar op.",
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            **"messages": [{
                                    "text": "Dit veld is verplicht",
                                    "type": "ERROR"
                                }**
                            ],
                            "name": "Motorrijtuig.Bouwjaar"
                        },
                        "type": "update",
                        "key": "3"
    }}]}]}
```

I want to validate that model with questionText='Bouwjaar' has message.text='Dit veld is verplicht'

A solution could be: 
${test} = Evaluate | '${JSON['events'][0]['changes']['changes'][2]['model']['messages'][0]['text']}'=='Dit veld is verplicht'

But with a new update the index could be changed and my test will fail.

My solution now is:
for each modelobject -> Check if questionText is in the modelobject -> YES -> check if questionText = Bouwjaar -> YES -> check message
In my jsonobject there are 14 modelobjects

Is there an easier way to check the message.text, without de indexcontext?

Comment: You have to be more specific than that, I mean - a lot more specific. We can't know what is the json schema, what is a significant key or list member, etc. Say for the specific case, what signifies an error? Speaking in general, I could answer you in general - itterate through the keys, their members, look for the subkey with the specific value and get the parent key/member index when you find it. But that's not very usable, is it? Same with the question in this format.

Comment: I asked for the JSON scheme but there isn't one. How ever, you do describe what i need. I'll try to simplify the JSON string. I specific interested in "get the parent key/member index"

Comment: With the updated description it is much more clear now; great. Your second solution is good - the one with "for each". As you have to make two nested loops - everywhere you've used an index in your example how to get to the "text" property should be a loop (3 if the `events` list is with more than one member), and RF doesn't support nested loops directly - you have to create a keyword for the child loop, being called by the parent one, it will be better off and much more readable in python. Do you need help with that?

Comment: i was afraid of that, so i ordered a python programming book B-) and yes i can use your help, but first i have some learning to do. I am really (and clearly) not a programmer/developer. I'll get back if that is possible :) and thx for the help